# How can I compile sass and bower install on heroku with a PHP app?

Tags: heroku, sass, bower

How can I compile sass and run bower install on heroku with a PHP (Laravel) app?

For Sass, everything seems to point to using Sass with rails. I have tried adding a script in my composer.json file and that doesnt work because Sass is not detected on heroku.

For bower, I tried adding a package.json, installing bower locally, and using that to run bower install but when I put a package.json file in my directory, it thinks my app is a node app so I cant get my Laravel app to even start.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dzuelke/heroku-multipack-nodejs-php-example is one way of doing that - the example runs both the Node and the PHP buildpack, so you'd have to add the Ruby buildpack to the beginning of the list as well and have a Gemfile that requires Sass.